# Resolve promise on array push - javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm attempting to define a function that returns a promise. The promise should resolve when a given array is set (`push()`).

To do this I'm attempting to use a Proxy object (influenced by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501151/1461850)):

```js
let a = []

;(async function(){

  const observe = array => new Promise(resolve =>
      new Proxy(array, {
          set(array, key, val) {
              array[key] = val;
              resolve();
            }
      }));

  while(true){

      await observe(a);
      console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),"Blimey Guv'nor:",`${a.pop()}`);
    }

})(a);

;(async function(){
    await new Promise(resolve => timerID = setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
    a.push('ʕ·͡ᴥ·ʔ');
    a.push('¯\(°_o)/¯ ')
})(a)
```

I can't see why this doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

More generally, **what is a good way to have a promise resolve on push to an array?**

Comment: You can take a look at the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309894/resolve-promise-or-add-callback-after-array-push-method

Comment: Thanks @Avior, despite its title that answer is about promises on a `fetch` command

Comment: [Properly building Javascript proxy set handlers for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528463/properly-building-javascript-proxy-set-handlers-for-arrays)

Comment: I don't think `await observe(a);` will ever resolve...

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks I agree, but why not?

Comment: `;(async function() { ... })(a);` - Passing `a` into the IIFE but not using it is useless. And you would have to store the result of `new Proxy()` as `a`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, am I not using it in `observe(a)`?

Comment: Firstly `while(true)` is infinitely looping. I can't see how it would ever get to the `a.push` lines.

Comment: Plus promises are only supposed to resolve once.

Comment: It's also going to wait for `observe` to resolve before it moves on to `a.push`, but since `a.push` is what resolves it, it will never resolve.

Comment: @evolutionxbox if you replaced the observe() statement with `new Promise(resolve => timerID = setTimeout(resolve, 5000))` it checks the array every 5s (and would run). But I want it to only do this on array push.

Comment: @BenFortune Thanks - I don't think I've misunderstood this - is there an obvious mistake?

Comment: As @BenFortune has stated, once a promise is resolved it can't be resolved again. Consider creating promises on each push, rather than once at the proxy creation.

Comment: @evolutionxbox my intention is that calling `observe(a)` creates a new promise. This should be then resolved in the new proxy object, when a is pushed to... A new promise is created every loop.

Comment: That isn't possible _in its current form_ due to the reasons I've already described.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a promise?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it needs to be accepted by the `await` statement

Comment: That's a technical restriction. I'm asking _why_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206278/discussion-between-atomh33ls-and-evolutionxbox).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no problem, thanks for taking the time to have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with your attempt:

- you invoke `.push` on the original array, not the proxied one. Where you create the proxy, it is returned to no-one: any reference to it is lost (and will be garbage collected).
- The code following after the line with `await` will execute asynchronously, so *after all* of your `push` calls have already executed. That means that `console.log` will execute when the array already has two elements. Promises are thus not the right tool for what you want, as the resolution of a promise can only be acted upon when all other synchronous code has run to completion. To get notifications *during* the execution *synchronously*, you need a synchronous solution, while promises are based on asynchronous execution.

Just to complete the answer, I provide here a simple synchronous callback solution:

```js
function observed(array, cb) {
    return new Proxy(array, {
        set(array, key, val) {
            array[key] = val;
            if (!isNaN(key)) cb(); // now it is synchronous
            return true;
        }
    });
}

let a = observed([], () =>
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),"Blimey Guv'nor:", `${a.pop()}`)
);

a.push('ʕ·͡ᴥ·ʔ');
a.push('¯\(°_o)/¯ ');
```

As noted before: promises are not the right tool when you need synchronous code execution.

#### When each `push` is executed asynchronously

You *can* use promises, if you are sure that each `push` happens in a separate task, where the promise job queue is processed in between every pair of `push` calls.

For instance, if you make each `push` call as part of an input event handler, or as the callback for a `setTimeout` timer, then it is possible:

```js
function observed(array) {
    let resolve = () => null; // dummy
    let proxy = new Proxy(array, {
        set(array, key, val) {
            array[key] = val;
            if (!isNaN(key)) resolve();
            return true;
        }
    });
    proxy.observe = () => new Promise(r => resolve = r);
    return proxy;
}


let a = observed([]);
(async () => {
    while (true) {
        await a.observe();
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),"Blimey Guv'nor:",`${a.pop()}`);
    }
})();

setTimeout(() => a.push('ʕ·͡ᴥ·ʔ'), 100);
setTimeout(() => a.push('¯\(°_o)/¯ '), 100);
```

Comment: Great points. The first really helped me understand my error. re. the second - I was not clear in the question (the array pushes should have been via the console, or after a delay). I'll adjust the question, thanks.

Comment: After your edit, the two `push` calls are still executed in the same synchronous piece of code (even though that piece itself executed asynchronously). There is no way a promise resolution would get in-between those two `push` calls. They really need to be each in a separate asynchronous job for a promise to have any chance to trigger a job in-between.

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Superb! In my use case, many of the push calls will indeed be asynchronous (again should have made that clearer). Thanks.